# Lifting capacity of superconductors

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, superconductivity, levitation

How does the strength of the magnetic field the superconductor is exposed to affect its ability to levitate/lock heavier objects? Or is there no relationship (for superconductors) between magnetic field strength and mass of lifted object? For example, could a weak magnetic field lift a small car with superconductors?

Comment: How you make a magnetic field is completely irrelevant for the force that a magnetic object will experience in it. Superconductors are merely handy for magnet building because they only need to be energized once and then the field stays, while ordinary electromagnets made from normal conductors keep consuming (a lot of) energy.